# Hostname, port and wlservercontext of MobileFirst on Bluemix Mobile Foundation

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud

I have done the following:

1. Created an account on Bluemix and added the "Mobile Foundation" service.
2. I have then logged into the MobileFirst Operations Console and created an iOS application
3. Downloaded the sample c=Cordova application and added platform iOS
4. The sample application has a button to test ping, which fails

I need the host name, port and wlservercontext to be set in the `mfpclient.plist` file. How/From where can I get these?

[image: descriptor file]

Comment: Thanks I tried this, but was getting the following error

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your application with the MobileFirst Server instance that you're running in the Mobile Foundation service.

Did you read the tutorial...? See here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/quick-start/

What you want to do is:

1. Ensure that you have the MobileFirst CLI installed (`npm install mfpdev-cli`)
2. Add the remote server to the CLI (`mfpdev server add`, [see example here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/using-the-mfpf-sdk/using-mobilefirst-cli-to-manage-mobilefirst-artifacts/#add-a-new-server-instance)
3. Register the app:

   - Navigate to the project root folder in command-line
   - Run the command: `mfpdev app register your-remote-server-name-from-step-2` - This step adds the details you've mentioned into the .plist file.
4. Build the app again in Xcode

Comment: Thanks
I tired this after creating a Mobile Foundation Service and changing the default password, but was always getting an error : 

Cannot connect to server 'BookLibBlueMixServer' at 'https://mobilefoundation-qi-zd-server.au-syd.mybluemix.net:443'.
Failed to set runtime details.: Unexpected token N in JSON at position 4: HTTP 404 - Not Found.

I later was able to successfully achieve this after creating a new Foundation service and doing a 'mfpdev server add' without changing the password.

Comment: For successfully pinging the server,  some user may require to change the protocol to http and port to 80 in the mfpclient.plist file